# In navigator.canShare i want to use custom text while sharing the image on whatsapp not url

Tags: javascript

```
async shareFile(file:any) {
    if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare({ files: [file] })) {
        await navigator.share({
          "title": this.shareTitle,
          "text": this.shareText,
          "files": [file],
        })
        .then(() => console.log("Share was successful."))
        .catch((error) => console.log("Sharing failed", error));
    } else {
      console.log(`Your system doesn't support sharing files.`);
    }
  };
```

[image]

this i am expecting above functionality to share the image.
I am using navigator.canshare

Comment: `this i am expecting above functionality to share the image.` and what happens instead? is your page in a secure context as required?